# Cannot update varchar column with special characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Originally i thought that this issue is related to C# `TransactionScope` or `Dapper.NET`. But since i have tested the sql in SSMS and the issue remains i assume that it's a pure sql issue.

This is the (simplified) update which should update a `varchar(40)` column. I don't get any errors and row-count is 1. The old `SparePartDescription` is `EC801/¦USB/Exch Acc/JP/PE bag`:

```
declare @rowCount int  

UPDATE [tabSparePart] SET 
    [SparePartDescription] = 'EC801/╡USB/Exch Acc/JP/PE bag'
WHERE ([idSparePart] = 13912)

set @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
select @rowCount
```

So the only difference are these special characters: `╡` and `¦`.

Maybe you have an idea why i cannot update this column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the special character you are using:

```
╡
```

Is not supported in ASCII. See:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(32) = 'EC801/╡USB/Exch Acc/JP/PE bag';
SELECT @x;
```

Result:

```
EC801/¦USB/Exch Acc/JP/PE bag
```

So the update is working fine, technically, it's just not doing what you want, because in order to fit into the ASCII space, it has to substitute your character for one that is valid.

In order to support that character, you'll have to use Unicode for your column (and maybe a specific collation, I'm not sure). This works fine:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(32) = N'EC801/╡USB/Exch Acc/JP/PE bag';
SELECT @x;
```

Result:

```
EC801/╡USB/Exch Acc/JP/PE bag
```

It will be important to specify the `N` prefix on string literals that contain such characters...

Comment: Thanks. I've totally forgotten  that varchar doesn't support unicode(as opposed to nvarchar) since i pretty much never need to store such characters. However, this was annoying since a windows-service tried to update thousands of rows because the column seemed to be different. Are there any drawbacks in changing the column from varchar to nvarchar?

Comment: Well, without Unicode compression, it doubles the storage space for the same characters - in 2008 and below, all Unicode data takes 2 bytes. In 2008 R2, Unicode compression treats all non-Unicode characters in a Unicode column as non-Unicode, saving quite a bit of space if Unicode is the exception.